# Using Restkit and Core data to Retrieve Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, restkit

I have a core data application using rest kit to retrieve data from a web service. The response i get from the webservice is a json string like this -

```
"nodeRef": "workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/b1d51831-990d-47a8-a018-f1c1bg33f594",
        "type": "document",
        "name": "x.jpg",
        "displayName": "x.jpg",
        "title": "myTestProject",
```

(This is some meta data around an image. If i want to retrieve this image then i should access it using this url - http://x.co.uk/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/b1d51831-990d-47a8-a018-f1c1bg33f594/content/thumbnails/ipad1024?c=force) - note ive changed the URL slightly so you wont be able to access it. Also you need to authentication to access the URL. So i was wondering how i would go about getting this image and storing it locally on my SQLite DB? I can obviously access the URL but how exactly do i prompt it to download the image

Answer (score 1):

What i did in this situation was to do a lazy load on the image with something like:

```
image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.absoluteUri]]];
NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, JPGCompression);
```

Then store it. Outside of Restkit. This was a while ago, but it worked for me.
Basically extract the URL from restkit, do a lazy load when the image is presented on the screen, and thne store it back to core data (or wherever) when you have loaded it once.
Hope this helps.